# Rails association for has one/belongs to vs has many/belongs to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I want to create two tables, one is Job and one is JobType.

Each Job has one job_type ie. Temp, Parttime or Fulltime.

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :job_type
end

class JobType < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :job
end
```

So my job_type table will look like this

```
id  type    job_id
1   temp      1
2   temp      2
3   fulltime  3
4   temp      4
```

It seems redundant...

Should I instead be doing, job belongs to job_type and job_type has many jobs like this?

```
id   name   job_type_id
1   waiter    1
2   waiter    2
3   clerk     1

id   type  
1    temp
2    fulltime
```

I'm confused. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Job can have many job types, the association will be like

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :job_type
end

class JobType < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :job
end
```

Otherwise you can give association like one job has many job_types and one job_type has many jobs.

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :job_type
end

class JobType < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :job
end
```

Comment: what if a job can only have one job type? it can only be full time or part time or temporary?

Comment: Oh by Job I meant like a job posting, I was using job posting as job should I create a new table for job_post?

Comment: If one job has only one job_type then you have to use has_one :job_type for association in the model.

Comment: Yes, for job_post you have to create another table which you can associate with jobs.

Answer (score 0):

This problem fits to [many-to-many relationship](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association).
A `job` has_many `job_types`, and any `job_type` can has_may `jobs`.

For this you will need a join table - `jobs_jobs_types`.

Your data will then look like:

```
jobs
id   name   
1   waiter  
2   clerk   

jobs_types
id   type  
1    temp
2    fulltime

jobs_jobs_types
job_id job_type_id
1 1
1 2
2 1
```

I will leave the code for you. :) You can get additional help in this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many).

Comment: what if the job table was actually job posting? do I use another table for that? i'm still a bit confused.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. According to question you asked originally and data you gave, a job is seen with multiple job types (and vice versa). Job table --> Job Posting is as per your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is just a simple programming language. It totally works as we speak.

```
For eg: A Posts has_many Comments and Comments belongs_to Post.
```

Over here u can clearly see that pluralization over here tells us that, there are many comments for a particular post.
The same idea works with has_one relation, User has_many Votes, and Votes belongs_to User.
So therefore in your case i suggest you to write your association as
job has_many types and job_types belongs to job.

So the job_types table of here will be using the primary key of your table jobs as foreign key for normaliziation of data.